# Variable declaration in switch-case statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, switch-statement

I have created a function day_of_week(dayy) and used switch-case statements in function.

```
function day_of_week(dayy) {
    var result;
    switch (dayy) {
        case 1:
            result = "monday";    
        case 2:
            result = "Tuesday";    
        case 3:
            result = "wednesday";    
        case 4:
            result = "thursday";    
        case 5:
            result = "friday";    
        case 6:
            result = "saturday";    
        case 7:
            result = "sunday";    
        default:
            result = "No day";
    }
    document.write(result);
}

document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = day_of_week(1);
document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = day_of_week(2);
```

Actually in switch-case statements if there is no "break" the code should execute randomly. But here when I declared variable called result and assigned the case values to it without "break". So, the code should execute all the cases randomly without any break. But, here the variable is under the instance of
redeclaring the value and executing the last case.
I am unable to know my mistake whether it is in declaring variable or using switch-case statements and all under the instance of function.
please help...

Comment: "should execute randomly"? What makes you think that this code will be anything other than deterministic?

Comment: If there is no break, the execution will "fall through". The statements in each matching case are run-it will not "break" out of the switch statement on the first matching case. So, each case will end up in the `default` case, and you'll end up with `No day`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "I tried setting a variable in every switch case without a break to see what would happen" is not a situation future readers will find themselves in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no break statement in your code. I hope this will work for you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function day_of_week(dayy){
   var result;
    switch(dayy){
      case 1: result = "Monday";
                         break;
         
        
        case 2: result = "Tuesday";
                          break;
        
        case 3: result = "wednesday";
                          break;
        
        case 4: result = "Thursday";
                          break;
        
        case 5: result = "Friday";
                          break;
        
        case 6: result = "Saturday";
                          break;
       
        case 7: result = "Sunday";
                          break;
        
        default: result = "No day";
   }
   document.write(result);

}
document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = day_of_week(2);

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually my doubt is that if there is no break statement in my code then all the days should display. But, in my code the variable result is redeclared by different cases and executing the last case value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to get a random day:

```
function getDay() {
    const days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

    return days[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
}
```

Comment: Actually my doubt is that if there is no break statement in my code then all the days should display. But, in my code the variable result is redeclared by different cases and executing the last case value.

Answer (score 0):

I refactor this code by using berak and Math method

```
function day_of_week(day) {
     

    var result;
    switch (day) {
        case 1:
            result = "monday";
                 break;
        case 2:
            result = "Tuesday";    
                 break;
        case 3:
            result = "wednesday";  
                 break;
        case 4:
            result = "thursday";  
                 break;
        case 5:
            result = "friday"; 
                 break;
        case 6:
            result = "saturday";  
                 break;
        case 7:
            result = "sunday";   
                 break;
        default:
            result = "No day";
    }
    document.write(result);
}

document.getElementById("switch").innerHTML = day_of_week(Math.floor( Math.random()*10));
```

Comment: Actually my doubt is that if there is no break statement in my code then all the days should display. But, in my code the variable result is redeclared by different cases and executing the last case value.